# why users and newUser are not equal?

Tags: javascript

```
const users = [
    {name:'John',age:24},
    {name:'Victor',age:28}
];

const newUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users));
console.log(users);
console.log(newUser);
console.log(typeof(users));
console.log(typeof(newUser));
console.log(users==newUser)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ { name: 'John', age: 24 }, { name: 'Victor', age: 28 } ]
[ { name: 'John', age: 24 }, { name: 'Victor', age: 28 } ]
object
object
false
```

object `users` and `newUser` have exactly same items and values.
They why `users==newUser` is false?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: In JavaScript, two objects aren't necessarily evaluated equal even if they share the same attributes and values. Refer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript/1144249#1144249).

Comment: you can have 2  cars of the same brand/model/color..., they will always remain different cars, it's the same for objects

Answer (score 0):

In `Javascript` the equals operator compares object instances, not values. They are 2 different instances, so not equal.

One way to compare the values is to use a `deep equals` library.  Another way is to compare the `JSON.stringify` value.

```
JSON.stringify(users) === JSON.stringify(newUser) // true
```

A caveat of the stringify approach is that `undefined` values are stripped.